# Do loop index changing on its own

Tags: loops, fortran

I have a couple hundred line program (including functions) in essentially free-form Fortran. At one point, I have a pair of nested do loops that call functions and store results in matrices. However, I don't believe any of that is the problem (although I could be wrong).

Immediately after the first do loop starts, I define an array using a column of another array. Immediately after that, the index is always set to 3. I haven't been able to find any useful information in the usual places. I've included a fragment of the code below.

```
do i = 1,n
   print *, 'i:',i        ! Gives i = 1
   applyto = eig_vec(:,i)
   print *, i             ! Gives i = 3
   state1 = create_state(ground,applyto,state,bin_state,num_s,ns)
   first = destroy_state(ground,state1,state,bin_state,num_s,ns)
   state1 = destroy_state(ground,applyto,state,bin_state,num_s,ns)
   second = create_state(ground,state1,state,bin_state,num_s,
 1  ns)
   do j = 1,n
    bra = eig_vec(:,j)
    a_matrix(j,i) = sum(bra*first + bra*second)
    matrix(j,i) = sum(bra*first - bra*second
   end do
  end do
```

Is this a bug? Am I missing something obvious? I am compiling the code with a high level of optimization, if that could potentially be a source of problems. I'm relatively new to Fortran, so debugging flags or commands (for gdb - I believe that's all I have available) would be welcome.

Comment: Could you post the code of `eig_vec`?

Comment: `eig_vec` is a rank 2 array, read from an external file. So there's not really any code involved, other than the read statement.

Comment: It's impossible to test this code for you in isolation from the rest of the program, some input data, *etc*.  On the face of it there is no possibility of `i` changing from `1` to `3` simply by assigning the value of `eig_vec(:,i)` to `apply`.  There may be some weird feature in your code, such as `equivalence`.  You may have posted a synopsis of your code rather than the code itself.  There may be a compiler bug.  Or you may be misreporting the problem, possibly misunderstanding it too.  We can't tell.

Comment: A guess from this fragment of code is that `applyto` is a smaller array than `eig_vec(:,i)` and that assignment is writing to memory outside of `applyto`.   How are the arrays declared?   Have you compiled with run-time subscript checking?  What compiler are you using?  With gfortran, try `-fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fcheck=all   -fbacktrace`.

Comment: @M.S.B., that plus a minor change appears to have fixed it. Apparently some unused variables were interacting badly with `i`. After fixing that, though, it also appeared as though the `destroy_state` and `create_state` functions (which also include `do` loops) were affecting the index - changing it to `l` seems to have solved the problem. Also, -fcheck=all gives "unrecognized command line option" - was this available in gfortran 4.4.7? Can't seem to find documentation on it.

Comment: I doubt you have really fixed it. Sounds strongly like an out of bounds error as M.S.B. suggests, so try -fbounds-check instead of -fcheck=all and see what happens. Your compiler is a little old and this is about the closest approximation you have.